# nuxt.js and vue.js how to use vuetify "Select " dropdown list

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

**i am using nuxt.js in my form i have vuetify "Select" Dropdown list but it not showing drop down item how to fix this error.**

```
<v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6" >
    <v-select :items="items" v-model.trim="form.city" label="Outlined style" outlined ></v-select>
</v-col>
<v-col cols="12" sm="12">
```

{{errors.GSTIN[0]}}


<v-file-input  v-model="form.shop_front_image" type="file" label="shop_front_image" outlined
autocomplete="off" @change="handleFile()" id="file">
{{errors.shop_front_image[0]}}

```
<script scoped>
  export default {
     
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          city:'',
          GSTIN: '',
          shop_front_image:'',
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleFile() {
        let input = document.getElementById("file")
        console.log(input)
        this.form.shop_front_image = input.files[0]
       
      },
      async submit() {
    
        let formData = new FormData(); 
        
        formData.append('city', this.form.city)
        formData.append('GSTIN', this.form.GSTIN)
        formData.append('shop_front_image', this.form.shop_front_image)
     
        console.log(formData)
     
        let rsp = await this.$axios.$post('/Businessregister', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
        console.log(rsp.response)
      }
   
      }
    }

</script>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: ['Mumbai', 'Delhi', 'Bangalore'],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You defined two `script`  tags, we dont have `scoped` for `script` tag,  `scoped` is for `style` tag

Comment: @Mohsen can you post your answer for batter understand thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer `items` from second script tag to first, and remove second `script` tag

```
<script>
  export default {
     
    data() {
      return {
        items: ['Mumbai', 'Delhi', 'Bangalore'],
        form: {
          city:'',
          GSTIN: '',
          shop_front_image:'',
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleFile() {
        let input = document.getElementById("file")
        console.log(input)
        this.form.shop_front_image = input.files[0]
       
      },
      async submit() {
    
        let formData = new FormData(); 
        
        formData.append('city', this.form.city)
        formData.append('GSTIN', this.form.GSTIN)
        formData.append('shop_front_image', this.form.shop_front_image)
     
        console.log(formData)
     
        let rsp = await this.$axios.$post('/Businessregister', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
        console.log(rsp.response)
      }
   
      }
    }

</script>
<style scoped>

<style>
```

`scoped` attribute is for `style` tag.

Comment: scoped attribute is for style tag. Got it

Comment: i have 2 more Dropdown if i changed :items="items" to :drop1="drop1" and :drop2="drop2" its not showing dropdown item how to fix this

Comment: `:items = "drop1"` , `items` is prop name and `drop1` is value assigned to it, same for second v-select `:items = "drop2"`